# Schedule Job doesn't work properly

Tags: scheduled-apex, scheduled-job, schedule

I have a Schedulable class named 'DeletarSemCheckinSchedule' that runs some DML's. i also have another Schedulable class named 'AgendarSchedulesCheckin'.
The 'AgendarSchedulesCheckin' should be called by itself every hour and the 'DeletarSemCheckinSchedule' should be called sometimes by 'AgendarSchedulesCheckin' either.

If I call the 'AgendarSchedulesCheckin' inside Developer Console with the code **bellow** the job is executed, but both 'DeletarSemCheckinSchedule' and 'AgendarSchedulesCheckin' aren't called again.

```
AgendarSchedulesCheckin abc = new AgendarSchedulesCheckin();
abc.execute(null);
```

**AgendarSchedulesCheckin**:

```
    global class AgendarSchedulesCheckin Implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
    {  
        Datetime horaAtual = datetime.now();
        Date dataAtual = horaAtual.date();
        Integer horaJob = horaAtual.hour();
        Integer diaJob;
        Integer mesJob;
        //Integer minute = horaAtual.minute();

        if(horaJob == 23){
            dataAtual = dataAtual+1;
            horaJob = 0;
        }else{
            //minute += 2; -- para teste
            horaJob += 1;
        }        

        diaJob = dataAtual.day();
        mesJob = dataAtual.month();

        String cron_exp = '0 40 '+horaJob+' '+diaJob+' '+mesJob+' ?';
        String jobName = 'jobTeste';
        System.Schedule(jobName, cron_exp, new AgendarSchedulesCheckin());

        PredialReservas__c PredialReservas = new PredialReservas__c();
        PredialReservas = [SELECT MinutosCheckin__c FROM PredialReservas__c WHERE Name = 'configBasica'];

        Integer tempoParaCheckin = (Integer) PredialReservas.MinutosCheckin__c;        
        Integer tamanhoFor = (60/tempoParaCheckin);        
        Integer minutoAux = 0;

        for(Integer x = 0; x < 3; x++){
            cron_exp = '0 '+minutoAux+' '+horaJob+' '+diaJob+' '+mesJob+' ?';
            jobName = 'jobTeste '+x;
            System.Schedule(jobName, cron_exp, new DeletarSemCheckinSchedule());
            minutoAux += tempoParaCheckin;
        }
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: @Eric No, no errors appers. The Schedule Job are not created on the second time.

Comment: @Bruno Perdigão Probably you must be getting . System.AsyncException: The Apex job named "xyz" is already scheduled for execution.  try to make jobName unique. eg. Add jobName = 'jobTeste '+x+System.now(); at both places where you are scheduling job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with one Schedule Class calling itself like this:

```
Integer tempoParaCheckin = (Integer) PredialReservas.MinutosCheckin__c;     
    System.debug('tempoParaCheckin - '+tempoParaCheckin);
    Integer qtdVezesRodaACadaHora = (60/tempoParaCheckin);
    System.debug('qtdVezesRodaACadaHora - '+qtdVezesRodaACadaHora);

    for (Integer i = 0; i < qtdVezesRodaACadaHora; i++) {
        String minuto = String.valueOf(i * (tempoParaCheckin));
        String CRON_EXP = '0 '+ minuto +' * * * ?';
        System.debug('CRON_EXP - '+CRON_EXP);
        //String CRON_EXP = '0 '+ minuto +' 5 * * ?';
        String jobName = 'Expira Reserva Predial '+i;
        System.schedule(jobName, CRON_EXP, new AgendarExpiraCheckin());
    }
```

Comment: super important to make jobname unique for all time as duplicate jobnames will be a major headache to deal with. Don't use `i`, use something like the job's start datetime